# Effects of land reforms in the 20th and 21st centuries

Tags: economy, political-history, agriculture, political-economy

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reforms_by_country) clearly shows, there have been many different land reforms in many different times and places. It seems there is enough data for research about the consequences of land reforms.

I am interested in a statistical assessment of the effects of land reforms on the economy. To allow quantitative analysis, I have focused on land reforms in the 20th and 21st century, where quantitative data (or at least estimates) of various economical indices are available.

I am looking for measurements of the effect of land reforms on indices such as: the gross domestic product, the Gini equality index, the inflation rate, and the currency exchange rate relative to neighbouring countries.

Obviously, there are different kinds of land reforms, that may have different effects. For example, land reforms done in formerly-feudal countries, based on democratic ideologies, are different than land reforms done in socialist or communist countries, based on Marxist ideologies. So, the above questions can be asked, for each kind of land reform separately.

Can you point me to research papers on this subject?

Comment: Bad subjective: unspoken methodological assumptions.  Off-topic: economy.

Comment: Also it looks too broad.

Comment: I think it is hard to answer this way. Just few problems with the question: Land reform made by democracies, communist states, in feudal systems, they both aimed different things, and had different effect. I am not giving -1, because the question itself might be good, but it should be more exact. Please edit!

Comment: @SamuelRussell: what are "unspoken methodological assumptions"? And why is it not related to economy?

Comment: You claim a capitalist economy is transhistorical.  Your question is about economic claims, not about economic history.  This isn't economics.se

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary: I agree, different kinds of land reforms may have different effects. A statistical analysis of land reform data may reveal such trends.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: so you criticize my use of modern terms such as GDP or Gini index? Very well, this makes sense. But still, land reforms have effects, and these effects can be quantified in some way. Maybe I should ask an earlier question: how can such effects be quantified in ancient non-capitalistic countries?

Comment: I believe this question is too broad - a book could easily be written on the topic.  The question also asks for a list of resources which is also discouraged by the FAQ.  There is some interesting stuff here, but I don't know how to edit the question down to one that is a good fit for H:SE

Comment: Would it be possible for the question to be limited to a number of known instances of land reform? I.e. How did Roman/Soviet/Industrial Revolution era land reforms effect their respective economies?

Comment: @Kobunite you are right, I probably should have started with specific questions such as the ones you mention. I jumped too fast to statistics, when the raw facts are not clear...

Comment: Maybe the question should be narrowed down to land reforms in the 20th-21th century, where more accurate numeric data can be obtained.

Comment: Yeah, if you edited your question to ask this instead and provided a couple of examples I think you'd be set.

Comment: OK, I narrowed the question down to the 20th-21th century